# A problem in a proof

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I was studying this theorem:

> If $X_1,X_2, \dots$ are *i.i.d.* with $E(X_1)=\infty$, then $P(|X_n|\geq n i.o)=1$. So if $S_n=X_1+\dots +X_n$ then $P(\lim S_n/n \space \text{exists}\in (-\infty , \infty))=0$.

Where this was written:

$$\frac{S_n}{n}-\frac{S_{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{S_n}{n(n+1)}-\frac{X_{n+1}}{n+1}$$

take $C=\{ \omega : \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n/n\space \text{exists} \in (-\infty, \infty)\}$,$S_n/(n(n+1))\to 0$. So, on $C\cap \{ \omega : |X_n|\geq n\space \text{i.o.}\}$, we have$$\large{|}\frac{S_n}{n}-\frac{S_{n+1}}{n+1}\large{|}>2/3\space\space \text{i.o.}(*^{\infty})$$.

In $(*^{\infty})$ why $2/3$, how did that value came?

**Note:** $(*^{\infty})\space \text{implies}\space (***\dots)$

i.o.= infinitely often

Comment: What do you mean by "i.o."?

Comment: infinitely often @Arthur

Comment: Instead of $2/3$, anything $<1$ works since the LHS is $|X_{n+1}|/(n+1)$, which is $\geqslant1$ i.o.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $C$, $\exists M >0$, $n>M \implies |\frac{S_n}{n(n+1)}| \leq \frac14$

On $\{ \omega: |X_n| \geq n \text{ }i.o.\}= \{ \omega: \frac{|X_n|}{n} \geq 1 \text{ } i.o.\}$

\begin{align}
\left| \frac{S_n}{n}-\frac{S_{n+1}}{n+1}\right| &= \left| \frac{S_n}{n(n+1)}-\frac{X_{n+1}}{n+1}\right| \\
& \geq \left|\left|\frac{X_{n+1}}{n+1} \right| - \left| \frac{S_n}{n(n+1)} \right|\right| \\
&\geq 1-\frac14 \text{ } i.o.\\
&> \frac23
\end{align}

Comment: thanks a lot Siong